# how to squeeze -1 in file

Tags: linux, bash, centos, tr, vcftools

I have a file like following

```
-1  1 -1
2  -1  2
-1  2  0
```

I want to squeeze the element "-1" by

```
tr -s  '-1' file
```

But it does not work.

**ADDED**

I use vcftools to change vcf.gz to matrix with element "0", "1", or "2"(say,chr1.012) (missing value will be "-1"). But I found length of each row is different. So I doubt whether it is because of "-1". So I want to squeeze "-1" element.

Comment: What do you mean by "squeeze"? Replace consequitive occurences of "-1" with a single "-1"?

Comment: @Mithrandir I want to treat "-1" as a single number

Comment: How should your output look like?

Comment: `tr` will only transliterate or squeeze characters on a one-for-one basis. Your `-1` is two characters, so you will need to use a different tool - probably `sed`, `awk` or `perl`.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with `tr`, because:

- `-1` will be treated as character set with two characters `-` and `1`, not a single token `-1`
- Also even if you have a single character, the occurrences are needed to be adjacent to let `tr` apply the squeeze operation

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a similar functionality in `sed`

```
$ echo "-1-1-1 2 -1" | sed -r 's/(-1)+/-1/g'
-1 2 -1
```

replaces contiguous stream of `-1`s with one instance.